# Node.js blog - when add post, everything is in one line

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a problem, I'm making a simple blog with node.js and when user add a post, no matter how many enters or spaces he press, everything is in one line.

I would like to have it nice, if I press 5 spaces- have 5 spaces. 
I thought also about posibility to let user use html tags like  etc.

Could you give me some advices how can I do that?

https://github.com/Lok3rs/Karolina-Cieplicka-Fotografia

That's all the code I have right now.

Thank you!

Comment: The easiest solution (without the html) would be displaying the data in a `<pre>here your content</pre>` tag.

Comment: Yes, but <pre> tag makes that if I have a long text it makes a vertical scrollbar instead of breaking lines

Comment: eventhoug html spacing is a complex issue that you should read about, a quick solution for your raw requirement would be, after user entry, just to replace all spaces with `&nbsp;` entities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without a minimum reproducable example, it's time consuming for anyone to give accurate advice. So my wild guess is you're using div's or the like to render the text, which by default will compress whitepsace.

```css
.preserve-whitespace {
  white-space: pre;
}
```

```html
<div>     leading,   trialing, and internal white    space     are  compacted  in divs   </div>
<pre>     leading,   trialing, and internal white    space     are **NOT** compacted  in pres   </pre>
<div class="preserve-whitespace">     this   can be   controlled with   the 'white-space'   style    </pre>
```

Look into the `white-space`, `overflow-wrap`, and `word-break` css properties for more customization.

Comment: Thanks! That helps me a lot!